# Taxonomy layout on node creation

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, theming

I have a content type with 5 taxonomies, each with 50 terms (checkbox). All of them are available for user to choose when creating node.

It looks really long and not quite user friendly.

So i am looking a module that can make this look nice. Table, inline, anything but default would look better.

Answer (score 1):

For these situations I prefer to use the [Chosen jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), which makes  elements way more user-friendly. For easy intergration of this plugin with Drupal, see the [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) module.

Comment: Its ok solution but still not what i need. I want to leave checkboxes on each term but to have them sorted in 3 or 4 columns, each containing same amount of terms.

Comment: In that case I think you have to integrate that in an admin (sub)theme